# How Spurious Hits in Rabin Karp algorithm equal to O (n/q)?

Tags: algorithm, hashmap, time-complexity, string-matching, rabin-karp

I am reading CLRS, In that I came across this line "We can then expect that the number of spurious hits is O(n/q), since the chance that an arbitrary ts will be equivalent to p, modulo q, can be estimated as 1/q."

I am putting website which contains full description under 34.2 topic

Please explain how we can expect the spurious  hits = O (n/q)

for reference http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap34.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of analysis, it is often assumed that the hash function used is `Simple Uniform Hashing`. This assumption states that every key is equally likely to be hashed to, independent of how other keys are hashed.

In other words, given `q` possible values a hash function can produce, the probability of each is `1/q`.

In the example you linked to, they discuss the *spurious hit* scenario, when two *different* strings hash to the same value. What is the probability of this event, given a Simple Uniform Hashing?

The first string is hashed to the value `x`. What is the probability that the second string will be also hashed to the value `x`? It's `1/q`.

I recommend [this lecture](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/lecture-9-table-doubling-karp-rabin/), which discusses Karp-Rabin algorithm.